# Copy data from URL into a file using curl and access the file at the same time

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I am copying data from URL into a file using curl library. I want to access the file at the same time as it is being written. But the file is not getting created.

```
    CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
static const char *filename = "stream.txt";
FILE *fileptr;

/* URL of the radio-station  */
char * webaddr =  "http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de:80/rockantenne-deutschland.aac";
curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl)
{

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, webaddr);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    fileptr  = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (fileptr)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fileptr);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        fclose(fileptr);
    }
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr,
                "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, you will make libcurl deliver all received data to that given callback *instead* of the default function (which is `fwrite()`).

So in order to both "use" the data and store it in a file, just make your callback function do that!

Alternatively, you don't set `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and just set a `FILE *` with `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` (however, this method does not work if you're on Windows and use libcurl as a DLL).

Comment: can i access file "stream.txt" while data is being written to it? I am not able to do that. The file itself is not getting created. Does the file "stream.txt" get created only after data is fully copied into it ?

Comment: Your code does the fopen() call so the file should be created there, yes. But note that you do that *after* curl is done with its first transfer.

Comment: File is getting created but data is not getting transferred to it.